# Sharing facebook post using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can share any link on facebook using this:

```
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'TagBin',
link: 'https://tagbin.in',
picture: '',
caption: 'tagbin-share',
description: 'tagBin provide a simple, consistent interface for sharing links.'
},
function(response){
  if (response && response.post_id) {
    alert('Post was published.');
  } else {
    alert('Post was not published.');
  }
})
```

but it opens a dialogue box, can i do it without opening dialogue box.
Thanks....

Comment: Do you want to load it within the page instead of popup? If that's the case then do check this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) about the `feed` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

On wall -->NO
On groups-->yes
better go with dilog otherwise this will lead to spamming